# Pycharm project imports modules incorrectly

Tags: python, flask, pycharm

I have a repo with a Flask webapp and a separate python directory, and I'm using PyCharm.

My project directory is:

```
/backup/
    __init__.py
    python modules etc
/webapp
    /py
        __init__.py
        /lib
            __init__.py
            python code
        /src
            __init__.py
            python code
    /static
        js, css, fonts etc
    /templates
        html
    webapp.py
```

I'm trying to import a module into webapp.py. This module exists in webapp/py/src/blah.py. blah.py has a class called Blah. I'm trying to write `blah = Blah()` before I import the module. I want pycharm to import it when I hit option + return. When I try importing through pycharm it imports it like this:

```
from webapp.py.src.blah import Blah
```

This doesn't work since webapp isn't a python package. When I change it to

```
from py.src.blah import Blah
```

it works. Is there any way I can get it to import properly? I *believe* I've had it working before. Then a group member decided almost every directory needed an `__init__.py` and I think that may have messed up pycharm. I tried flushing the cache but it doesn't work. Any solutions?

Comment: Since PyCharm is a commercial product and Jetbrains pays people to answer questions, have you tried their official support channels? Just asking, I think their customer service is very good.

Comment: Thanks Paulo. I actually have it under a student license so didn't think about doing that. Will give it a try.

Comment: I am not saying it will work, but you may try playing around marking/unmarking certain directories as source in the project options

Comment: Thanks gg, I did try that with no luck..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The webapp directory, as shown, is not a Python package.  It does not contain an `__init__.py` file, therefore it cannot be included in an import path.  You appear to have set up your Python path so that the webapp directory is on the path, which is why packages under it are importable (the py directory).

So this is a problem with how you've structured your project, not with PyCharm.  For an example of the "right" way to structure a Flask app and related data, see the source code for Python chat room's website: https://github.com/sopython/sopython-site.

Basically, you need to run from the directory that should be on your path, each of the packages should be within this directory (and should be packages with `__init__.py`).  Neither myapp or backup should be on the Python path, only project.

```
/project
    /run.py
    /myappp
        __init__.py
    /backup
        __init__.py
```